# Firebird Embarcado

Tags: delphi-xe3, firebird

Fiz uma aplicação que quero usar o Firebird embarcado, sigo todos os passos da dicas na net, mas na minha máquina funciona mas quando mando para outro computador não consegue achar a DLL.

Segui os passos do [deste tutorial](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/113/criando-uma-aplicacao-%22embarcada%22-com-o-firebird.aspx), mas o erro persiste. Se eu tento usar a DLL `fbembed.dll` meu sistema não encontra, coloquei uma cópia no `system32`, no `SysWoW64` do Windows e uma cópia onde esta o executável, porém não deu certo, mudei o nome da DLL para `gds32.dll` e o erro persiste.

Comment: Boa sorte! uma pergunta tem diferença grande entre os pcs?
tipo um 32 bits e o outro 64?
versões do windows ou coisa do tipo, 
pode ser problema de compatibilidade. 
mas isso é só um chute, não manjo nada sobre esse assunto

Comment: realmente eu prestei atenção nesta situação, sao dois computadores 64, ja tentei tb com a dll de 32 e tive o mesmo problema...

Answer (score 1):

Depois que o **Joanis** Comentou eu resolvi acatar a sua ideia:
Apaguei todas as DLL gds32.DLL, fbembed.dll 
Baixei uma versão limpa do Firebird-2.5.3.26778-0_Win32_embed e reinstalei tudo usando as bibliotecas Win32, ai deu tudo correto, acredito que o sistema estava lendo em algum lugar a DLL Errada, mas para constar deu certo com a DLL win32 mas o windows instalado no computador e x64, portanto para desencargo de consciência testei em mais um computador e duas maquina virtual e tudo saiu perfeito.